# Send data between two python Scripts in continous succession

Tags: python, sockets

I basically want to send data from one python file to the other, then have the other python file send some more data back to the first file, and then the first file send data again, and this goes on until I choose to stop sending data.

server.py:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 5409
s.bind((host, port))

s.listen(1)
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()  
    print 'Got connection from', addr
    while True:
        message = raw_input(">>")
        s.sendall(message)
        try:
            print s.recv(1024)
        except:
            print ""
```

client.py:

```
import socket               

s = socket.socket()         
host = "127.0.0.1"         
port = 5409                 

s.connect((host, port))
while True:
    print s.recv(1024)
    message = raw_input(">>")
    s.send(message)
```

I have been trying for a while and I have found nothing online other than a server and client that send data once between them and then close the connection. What can I do?

Comment: You mean "Python scripts" or "Python programs," not "Python files." Otherwise, it sounds as if you want to stream the content of one file into another file.

Comment: yeah sorry that's what i meant

Comment: As for the problem itself: is the communication fully-duplex (any program sends the data at any time) or strictly request-response?

Comment: currently, request-response is sufficient for the task i need to perform

Comment: In the server, you need to use the socket (`c`) returned by `s.accept()`.

Comment: how can I do that ?

Comment: ok so everything works now, but how can i make it so that the communication is fully-duplex ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in server.py

replace `s.sendall(message)` and `s.recv(1024)` with `c.sendall(message)` and `s.recv(1024)`.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to try zmq library. Great one for this kind of stuff.
Start server, then start client server will stay open until you send trough client to close server. Hope it helps!

More about zmq you can see [here](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:all)

Server listener

```
    import time
    import zmq
    import json
    from datetime import datetime

    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
    socket.bind("tcp://*:50165")
    import re

    while True:
        #  Wait for next request from client
        message = socket.recv()

        message = str(message)
        print(datetime.now(),message)

        #  Send reply back to client
        socket.send(b"Data Recieved")
```

Client

```
import zmq
from time import sleep
context = zmq.Context()

#  Socket to talk to server
print("Connecting to hello world server…")
socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket.connect("tcp://localhost:50165")

sleep(2)
#  Do 10 requests, waiting each time for a response
for request in range(10):
    print("Sending request %s …" % request)
    socket.send(b"1Hello")
    sleep(0.01)
    #  Get the reply.
    message = socket.recv()
    print("Received reply %s [ %s ]" % (request, message))
```